# How to pass PCI compliance when MsDeploy requires WMSVC certificate?

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, pci-compliance

I have a build server running Bamboo for continuous integration, which deploys to another server running the live site.

I'm currently working on getting the latter server PCI compliant and am unable to resolve an issue with the presence of the self-signed (WMSVC) Web Management Service certificate, which is apparently required for MsDeploy to succeed.

I have very little experience with MsBuild/MsDeploy (another developer set this up long ago), but I'm hoping there is a simple way around this conflict.

Comment: I don't think that a self signed cert would be a requirement for any application especially an MS one. It may require a cert but self signed are commonly untrusted. Find a free certificate issuer (there are plenty) back up and move your orginal certificate then follow the issuers guide to creating a new cert, Install it and test, im sure you will find the new cert is valid you can then go ahead and purchase a more readily recognised one if you wish but if "self signed" is your only block you wont need to. if the self signed is then found to be needed, just move it back into place.

Comment: It's required for deployment over SSL apparently, which makes sense, but what I was missing was that it can be **any** cert, including the licensed cert we already have for the site, not one specifically for WMSVC. Your answer got me pointed in the right direction so thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad that i could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was deploying over SSL, which requires at least a self-signed certificate. PCI compliance fails over the presence of a self-signed certificate so the answer was simply to delete that one and assign our licensed SSL certificate in IIS Management Service.